# How to solve the following system of diophantine equations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

We have the equations

$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1,$$
$$a_2x^2+b_2y^2+c_2z^2=d_2,$$
$$a_3x^3+b_3y^3+c_3z^3=d_3,$$

where $a_i,b_i,c_i \in\Bbb N$ at $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ are known.

Is there an efficient ($O(\log(d_1d_2d_3))$ time) procedure to find 
$x,y,z\in\Bbb N$ as solutions sought?

I can reduce the system of equations to
$$c_1^2a_2x^2+c_1^2b_2y^2+ c_2(d_1-a_1x-b_1y)^2=c_1^2d_2,$$
$$c_1^3a_2x^2+c_1^3b_2y^2+ c_3(d_1-a_1x-b_1y)^3=c_1^3d_3.$$

Comment: could you please post?

Comment: I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

This system can be routinely reduced to a single univariate polynomial using resultants -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant

Comment: It might be mentioned that "generically" this polynomial will have degree $6$, resulting in $6$ solutions (usually not in integers, of course).  In special cases you may have more solutions or less.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Could you explain how to solve over integers?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Could you explain the resultants technique?

Comment: @Turbo: Briefly speaking, the system $\{ p_1(x,y,z)=0, p_2(x,y,z)=0, p_3(x,y,z)=0 \}$ reduces to $\{ R_z(p_1,p_2)=0, R_z(p_1,p_3)=0 \}$ and then to a single equation $R_y(R_z(p_1,p_2),R_z(p_1,p_3))=0$ (of a single variable $x$), where $R_z$ and $R_y$ are resultants computed with respect to variables $z$ and $y$, respectively.

Comment: Once you have the polynomial (which will have integer coefficients), you want to check whether it has integer roots.   Let's suppose the constant coefficient is so large you can't just check its factors.  You might use Sturm's theorem to count the number of real roots; you can also bound the roots by easy inequalities.  Then by repeatedly bisecting intervals and using Sturm's theorem, you can isolate roots in small enough intervals to check the integers in them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maple found closed for and the complexity is finding the rational roots of degree 6 univariate polynomial and then substitute in messy expressions.

The closed form is 300KB in text in expanded form and is available here:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jor0/a9afaaf0b09c66d27edb/raw/9bf17e45e804d88dd796e6ad09b36fe7275cde79/turbo1.txt

It involves computing expressions depending on $a_i,b_i$, so in case they are large and $d_i$ are very small the complexity will depend on $a_i,b_i$ too.

Comment: could you post maple code as well?

Comment: @Turbo here it is:  `q1:=[a1*x+b1*y+c1*z-d1,a2*x^2+b2*y^2+c2*z^2-d2,a3*x^3+b3*y^3+c3*z^3-d3];so:=solve(q1,[x,y,z]);  `

Comment: That huge general expression is not particularly useful.  Given particular coefficients, it's better to compute the Groebner basis or resultants using those coefficients.

Comment: @joro Is this over $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Turbo No, it is over the rationals. In general the number of solutions is finite (possibly only unless the third equation is identically zero). From the finite solutions find the natural ones.